# failed to connect code -1 aerospike

Tags: node.js, pm2, aerospike

> 15:13:41 PM [error] Error  { AerospikeError: Failed to connect
>       6|vertica- |     at Object.client.getProdServerConnection_152 (/home/tech/processes/vertica-domain-distribution/connectors/connector-aerospike-js/connection/client.js:34:16)
>       6|vertica- |     at Module._compile (module.js:641:30)
>       6|vertica- |   name: 'AerospikeError',
>       6|vertica- |   message: 'Failed to connect',
>       6|vertica- |   code: -1,
>       6|vertica- |   func: 'as_cluster_seed_nodes',
>       6|vertica- |   file: 'src/main/aerospike/as_cluster.c',
>       6|vertica- |   line: 375 } (in /home/tech/processes/vertica-domain-distribution/connectors/connector-aerospike-js/connection/connection.js:74)
>       6|vertica- |  (in /home/tech/processes/vertica-domain-distribution/master.js:213)`

Getting this error while I'm trying to connect 25 times to aerospike using **batchread function** nodejs client, What I have to do? Providing service part of my aerospike.conf  file, Need anything to change ??

```
service {
  user root
  group root
  paxos-single-replica-limit 1 # Number of nodes where the replica count is automatically reduced to 1.
  pidfile /var/run/aerospike/asd.pid
  service-threads 4
  transaction-queues 4
  transaction-threads-per-queue 4
  proto-fd-max 100000
  proto-fd-idle-ms 10000
}
```

Comment: I think the Error codes are based on the Aerospike C client. github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-c/blob/master/src/include/… and seems like a client side error. Are you able to connect to the  server from an aerospike tool (asadm -h, asinfo -h...) from same client machine.

Comment: yes I'm connecting through aql